# Attaching images into Notes for iCloud Web

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I use Apple's Notes app on my Mac, iPhone and iPad. At times, I need to log into Notes for iCloud via a Web browser (using another Mac, PC or Linux box) using the web application to access my notes without the usual apps.

- https://www.icloud.com/#notes2

While I am easily able to add an image in Notes for iOS (by inserting) and Notes for macOS (by dragging), I couldn't find a way to add images to a note using Notes for iCloud Web interface.

Is it possible to add an image (using a desktop file explorer app) to Notes for iCloud web app?

To clarify, I am looking for a way to add image(s) from a public/non-personal computer where I don't have access to my iPhone, iPad or Mac. Only possible way to access notes in this case is via iCloud web site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the current implementation, it is not possible to attach images and any other file/media supported by Notes app on macOS/iOS via the iCloud Web client.

There is no control in the Notes Web app UI to attach images/supported files, neither does dragging and dropping image(s) work.

Although the lack of feature is not directly mentioned, the help document for Notes for iCloud Web (accessed by tapping the `?` in the header area) makes a cursory remark about requiring macOS/iOS device for attaching items.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The year is 2021, and adding an image to a note from a web browser is still not possible. Great job Apple!

Comment: The year is 2022 and nothing has changed. This means this is an intended business decision to not allow pasting images from anywhere apart from an Apple device.

Comment: Adding my +1 that in October 2022 we still can't paste images into icloud.com/notes. The iCloud browser apps might as well be read-only.

Comment: Adding +1 May 2023 and still an issue

Comment: August 2023, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the only way to add images to a note from the web browser is copy and pasting from a different note.

I know this is a horrible answer but its the only thing that is seemingly possible.

Comment: I log into iCloud for Web on a Windows PC. None of my other notes have an image. I do not have access to any of my devices. I have an image on my Desktop. How do I get that image into a note?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes I know. But I don't think it is possible. The only way is C&P. You can how ever create a "Note" in pages, which allows you to add image.s

Comment: I have edited the question to add clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answer the question but if what you need is, like me, to copy an image from PC to Notes Web so that I can doodle/work with it on iPad, it seems Pages Web does support pasting whereas Notes Web does not.

So my workaround is to paste the image on a document on Pages Web, open the document on my iPad, and copy the image from there. Such a hassle but at least it works for me.

Comment: While it doesn't exactly answer the question, this is the response I find most helpful.  This gives a helpful workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I do it (in my bootcamp partition-so same computer) is to save the clipping on a shared disk, make a marker in my note about the screenshot and
when in MacOS I go to the shared disk and note and drag them in the note at the right place.
Horrible workflow I know, but having to move on, it's the closest to a workflow I have found.
Shame on Apple for not providing a better integration.
I want to keep my notes (at the moment) in the notes app but might consider a cross platform (with synchronisation to iphone, mac, Ipad) if that should at all exist!